# Android: Automatic scrolling while entering text in AutocompleteTextView in CardView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using AutocompleteTextView in Cardview. While I click AutocompleteTextview to enter text, the RecyclerView will scroll automatically and AutocompleteTextview will not be visible. This happens even while entering the text in AutocompleteTextview. XML for this item is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/formatting_image_view"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/connect"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#00000000"/>
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding this the above view programmatically in CardView.
Any advice ?

Comment: do you have scrollbars enabled? There is an issue we are looking into where focus preservation does not work when scrollbars are enabled. If you disable them and use 21.0.2, it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, scrollbars is enabled. ok. I will try without scrollbars. Thanks.

Comment: Disabling scrollbar doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, for previous comment, it does solve the issue. Thanks.